# How to manage correctly file security permissions in windows

Tags: 7, files

In ["Securing file permissions and ownership"](http://drupal.org/node/244924) there is a little bit of what to do to manage security in **windows**, but it isn't step by step enough... Has anyone already done these configurations in windows ? How do we exactly and explicitly do ?

Comment: Windows permissions simpler, so you can pass it...

Comment: but after each node editing I get this : `Warning : file_put_contents(temporary://fil3808.tmp) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1903 in (...) \includes\file.inc).` I've changed my folders to write and read but it doesn't change

Comment: did you setup correctly temp folder in drupal admin?